# Can auto creation of unique index for unique constraint be disabled?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Creating unique constraint auto creates an unique index.

Is there any way to disable the creation of the index as I dont need an index on this column.

Comment: No - and why on earth would you want to stop this from happening?

Comment: Why not? Is the index responsible for ensuring uniqueness? Isn't the constraint itself ensuring uniqueness? I don't want to create unnecessary indexes in my database.

Comment: Because *not* knowing the order of the data would be awful for performance. Imagine having 10,000s of values and then being given another and asked to ensure its not in the existing values. All those values you have are an unordered mess; how quickly could you do this? Now put those values in a useful order, I bet you could do the same task far quicker. SQL Server is no different.

Comment: @variable, think about what SQL Server would need to do to guarantee uniqueness if no unique index existed; it would need to lock and scan the entire table.

Comment: One thing you can do, is change the unique constraint to a unique index, you can then add `include` columns and make the index more useful

Comment: Charlieface, so you see saying that instead of creating an unique constraint I should create an unique index wirh include columns? I'm just confused between this constraint and index thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable the creation of the index as I dont need an index on this column.

No.  Because as you guessed, the index is responsible for ensuring uniqueness.  Ie the Unique Constraint is *implemented* by creating a unique BTree index.